# Given a minimizing geodesic, is there a normal neighborhood containing this geodesic?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $(M,g)$ be a riemannian manifold. Let $\gamma : [0,1] \to M$ be a constant speed minimizing geodesic in $M$. Is there an $U \subset M$ normal neighborhood containing $\gamma$?

My main interest is actually another question: is there an $U \subset M$ open set, such that $U$ contains $\gamma$ and $r$, the radial distance function from $\gamma(0)$, is smooth in $U$?

Edit:
I changed the desired property of the radial function.

For me, a normal neighborhood of a point $p \in M$ is an open set $U \subset M$ containing $p$ such that the exponential map at $p$ is a diffeomorphism (that is, there is a $V$ in $T_pM$ with \exp_p(V) = $U$, and $V$ is a diffeomorphism there).

The whole point is to define the smooth field $\partial_r$ in such a way that $\dot{\gamma}$ is an extendible vector field along $\gamma$.

Comment: what does normal neighborhood means in this case? What property does it satisfy?

Comment: I'll edit the question with the specifications.

Comment: Hint: if $\gamma(1)$ is in the cut locus of $p=\gamma(0)$, then $r(q)= d(p,q)$ is not smooth at $\gamma(1)$, hence it cannot be smooth on $U$. I should also point out that $d(p,\cdot)$ is never smooth at $p$. So the example of the 1-dimensional sphere of circumference 2 provides a negative answer to your main question.